# Core plot - pie chart not showing enough segments

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-plot

In `numberOfRecordsForPlot:...` I have this code:

```
int count = [[optsDict objectForKey:@"Values"] count];
NSLog(@"pie count: %i", count);
return count;
```

It outputs `pie count: 4` thus (unless I'm misinterpreting) there should be 4 segments to the pie chart.

Then in `numberForPlot:(CPPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index` I have this:

```
double percentage = ((float)counter/(float)total)*100;
num = (NSDecimalNumber *)[NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:(int)percentage];

NSLog(@"index: %i, percentage: %f", index, percentage);
NSLog(@"%@", num);

return num;
```

This outputs:

```
index: 0, percentage: 9.090909
9
index: 1, percentage: 9.090909
9
index: 2, percentage: 63.636364
63
index: 3, percentage: 18.181818
18
```

So I am assuming (reasonably) that the function is getting run once for each segment and its returning a figure for all of them!

However the chart looks like this:

[image]

Theres not really much else I can tell you. Thats all I know, I don't know much about core plot!

If there is ANY help you can give me I'd be very appreciative!

Thank you

Comment: What colors are used for chart drawing?

Comment: I didn't choose any. But I then set the colors to a gradient and there's definitely two slices...

Comment: Check my answer and tell me, please, if it solved your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I play with your values and I think I found the problem in your code.

Try to return in `-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index` object of class `NSNumber`

```
num = (NSNumber *)[NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)percentage];
return num;
```

I was testing this in sample that is included in CorePlot framework. Firstly I tried to init `contentArray` array with `NSNumbers`:

```
NSMutableArray *contentArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:9.0909099], [NSNumber numberWithInt:9.0909099], [NSNumber numberWithInt:63.63636463], [NSNumber numberWithInt:18.181818], nil];
```

And everything works perfect. Then I've tried to init array as in your code with `NSDecimalNumbers`:

```
NSMutableArray *contentArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:9.0909099], [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:9.0909099], [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:63.63636463], [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:18.181818], nil];
```

And I've received exactly your double colored chart.

Hope this will help you =)

Comment: This was exactly it! The pie chart seems to work perfectly! I didn't even think about this! :) Thank you so much. So happy. Have 150 rep with pleasure.

Comment: I have to wait 3 hours to send rep. :) Sorry.

Comment: Oh, glad to here that =) I'm now working with CorePlot and it is very hard to work with it, documentation is very bad... Sometimes I'm looking in there source code to understand how it works. So it's normal that there are a lot of questions about CorePlot and too few answers.

Comment: You found a bug in the pie chart that is now fixed. It should work with both NSNumber and NSDecimalNumber.

Answer (score 0):

Do you implement

```
- (CPTFill *)sliceFillForPieChart:(CPTPieChart *)pieChart recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

which is in the CPTPieChartDataSource protocol?  Since there are no borderlines between sections, it might be drawing several with the same color.  Make sure you're returning a different color CPTFill for each index.

Comment: I did that with a gradient but there are definitely only two slices.

Answer (score 0):

Thomas i have done this pia chart using titanium framework.You have to use java script for display pia chart

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I'm displaying a lot of charts on one page (in a table view) and that many webviews would be incredibly slow. :) I'm not using the titanium framework either. I'm using iOS

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you missed first and second slices. `numberOfRecordsForPlot` can return 4, but in `numberForPlot` some code returns `nil`.. I created a new Pie Chart with your values, and all works nice. See code below.

You can also try to see data labels for every slice in the  `-(CPLayer *)dataLabelForPlot:(CPPlot *)plot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index` delegate method. If you really have 4 slices then 2 of them will placed at the same position. Code below is as well.

[image]

```
-(void) viewDidLoad{
    NSMutableArray *contentArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:9], [NSNumber numberWithInt:9], [NSNumber numberWithInt:63], [NSNumber numberWithInt:18], nil];
    self.dataForChart = contentArray;

    // Add pie chart
    CPPieChart *piePlot = [[CPPieChart alloc] init];
    piePlot.dataSource = self;
    piePlot.pieRadius = 100.0;
    piePlot.identifier = @"Pie Chart 1";
    piePlot.startAngle = M_PI;
    piePlot.sliceDirection = CPPieDirectionClockwise;
    piePlot.delegate = self;
    [pieChart addPlot:piePlot];
    [piePlot release];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Plot Data Source Methods
-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPPlot *)plot{
    return [self.dataForChart count];
}

-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    if ( index >= [self.dataForChart count] ) return nil;

    if ( fieldEnum == CPPieChartFieldSliceWidth ) {
        return [self.dataForChart objectAtIndex:index];
    }
    else {
        return [NSNumber numberWithInt:index];
    }
}

-(CPLayer *)dataLabelForPlot:(CPPlot *)plot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    CPTextLayer *label = [[CPTextLayer alloc] initWithText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", index]];
    label.textStyle.color = [CPColor lightGrayColor];
    return [label autorelease];
}
```